# How to bring app to foreground from background in Ionic 2?

Tags: api, ionic2

Is there any possible way to bring app from `background` mode in to `foreground` when an event happens like notification arrive? like **WhatsApp** and **Skype** that bring into foreground when a voice call or video call arrive.

**Update:**

```
public subscribeToPushNotificationEvents(): void {

    // Handle token refresh
    this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(
      token => {
        //console.log(`The new token is ${token}`);
        this.saveToken(token);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error refreshing token', error);
      });

    // Handle incoming notifications
    this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(
      (notification: NotificationModel) => {

         this.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();

        let notificationAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: notification.title,
          message: notification.body,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        notificationAlert.present();
}
```

Comment: How did you get this problem solved in your app finally?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your only option is this plugin: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

Comment: I have updated but the app is not going to foreground and sometimes app crashing. crashing is not related to `         this.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();` code.